# How to select all values in a column by column number in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find an elegant way to select all values in a given column on another sheet, based on it's number. I also need to exclude the first row.

I figured that this would be simple but am surprised how much of a headache it has been.

One method has been this:

```
=INDEX(OtherSheet!$A$2:$H$15, 0, <colNum>)
```

but this relies on hoping that $H is the last column and $15 is the last row.

Second attempt:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("OtherSheet!R1C"&<colNum>, FALSE), 1, 0, 15)
```

But I have to hardcode the number of rows here as well.

This seems like this is such a simple thing to do, am I just missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: What row has the most values and are they numbers, dates, booleans, text or a mix? What column has the most values and are they numbers, dates, booleans, text or a mix?

Comment: It's unknown which row has the most columns. They are all text fields

Comment: Then you will likely require VBA for .CurrentRegion or .SpecialCells(last cell).

Comment: try using counta on one of your columns to get the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

To return the last row containing data of a given column, using a formula and given that

- wSheet is a named range containing the worksheet name
- colNum is a named range containing the  desired column number

---

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN(INDIRECT(wSheet & "!C" & colNum,FALSE))>0),ROW(INDIRECT(wSheet & "!C" & colNum,FALSE)))
```

To return a range which refers to that column from Row 2 to the last row, you can combine `INDIRECT` with the `ADDRESS` function:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,colNum,1,1,wSheet)&":"&ADDRESS(LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN(INDIRECT(wSheet & "!C" & colNum,FALSE))>0),ROW(INDIRECT(wSheet & "!C" & colNum,FALSE))),colNum,1,1))
```

One issue with this method is that it will return `0`'s for empty or blank cells